# ASP.NET: Could not load type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, master-pages

I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not load type 'Intel.Intel'.
```

I copied my entire Visual Studio 2010 folder before I formatted my computer and I copy/replaced the same folder with this one after I installed windows again.  I'm running this locally not on a host server.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've search google and find many pages giving solutions for this, but none seem to fix my problem. Let me know if I need to provide anymore additional information. Thanks!

**Update:** Sorry I was unclear I copied the "Visual Studio 2010" folder from under my documents.  I've installed Visual Studio 2010 Premium from my MSDN account.

**Update 2:** I also forgot that I was getting this error below before the Could not load type error.  I fixed it by replacing the "~" with ".".  The strange thing is that while that will seem to fix that error -- If I try locating the file through the "Pick Master.." option when retyping "MasterPageFile=" it will give me the path with the tilda and yet it wont work. I don't know if this helps identify the overall problem or not.

```
The file '/Intel.Master' does not exist.
```

And below notice the "~/Intel.Master" -- as mentioned above I can get rid of this error by changing that to "./Intel.Master"

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Intel.Master" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.vb" Inherits="Intel.Index" %>
```

Comment: Did you manually re-add the reference to the dll from your project? Even if you copied everything exactly the old reference might be written in a file, and not found.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do what your saying. The project is a very simple one and while I know I have a dll I'm not sure how to re-add the reference. Thanks!

Comment: Right click your project, then click the Add Reference option, then click the Browse tab and browser for your dll, double click the dll, and recompile. This should work.

Comment: Ok I tried this and it added the file but I still get the same message. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution.

I looked in IIS Manager and I found that my application was a folder icon and not an application icon.  So I right clicked it and selected "Convert to Application".  After doing this it solved that error and now I have another one. I feel however that this solution did "fix" the problem.

Comment: The name can vary in different hosting providers, e.g In godaddy hosting, this option is called **Set Application Root**.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of registry settings that would be missing installing in this manner. Also there are components (shared) that are installed outside of the VS2010 folder.

Your best bet would be to re-install Studio in the usual (from media) route.

Based on EDIT:

The types that are missing look like they were previously stored in the GAC. Delete the reference in the project and re-create referencing the actual assembly file (DLL)

Comment: Sorry I was unclear was referring to the folder under the `My Documents` folder.  See Update on question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add the reference back in to you project, open your project, drop down your solution folder, then your projct - find the references node, right click it choose add refernce, go to browse .net assemblies and or file tab depending on where the dll is, find your dll and double click on it.

Comment: Tried adding the reference and still does not work even after adding this. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

Replace the `CodeBehind` By `CodeFile` and remove the namespace. before the `Inherits` class name. For example:

Wrong:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
MasterPageFile="~/Intel.Master" **CodeBehind**="Index.aspx.vb"
Inherits="**Intel.Index**" %>
```

Right:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Intel.Master" **CodeFile**="Index.aspx.vb"
Inherits="**Index**" %>
```

it works I promise